# Declare variable only with part of class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

Let's say we have a class like:

```
class House {
    street: string;
    pools: number;
    helicopterLandingPlace: boolean;
}
```

Now i build a service to update my house.

```
putHouse(house: House) {
    // some put request
}
```

But sometime I expect just parts of the house to get updated.

```
patchHouse(house: ?????) {
    // some patch request...
}
```

What is the cleanest way to declare the variable house with in the second function.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be by using the `Partial` type, something like:

```js
class House {
    street: string;
    pools: number;
    helicopterLandingPlace: boolean;
}

function patchHouse(house: Partial<House>) {
    console.log(house);
}

patchHouse({street: 'street'});
```

#### Under the hood

`Partial<T>` is an interface that has the following definition:

```
type Partial<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: T[P]; };
```

Which means that by using the `keyof` operator we get something like:

```
Partial<House> {
  street: string?;
  pools: number?;
  helicpterLandingPlace: boolean?;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Interface segregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle):

```
interface Addressable {
    street: string;
}

interface Swimmable {
    pools: number;
}

interface Landable {
    helicopterLandingPlaces: boolean;
}

class House implements Addressable, Swimmable, Landable {
    street: string;
    pools: number;
    helicopterLandingPlaces: boolean;
}

function patch(house: Swimmable) {
    house.pools++;
}
```

Comment: What if we had ten properties? We would end with 10 interfaces

Comment: Group the interfaces so they make sense. You don't have to make a separate interface for each property. In practice you'll probably have a bunch of properties that'll always be used together and that make logical sense together.